# Inverse FFT from scipy returns almost blank image

Tags: scipy, fft

I've started using fftpack from scipy, and I have a wierd problem. The following basic script returns a blank image:

```
image = plt.imread("moonlanding.png")
plt.imshow(image)
img_fft = np.abs(fftpack.fft2(image))
plt.show()
final_image = fftpack.ifft2(img_fft).real
plt.imshow(final_image)
plt.show()
```

[image]

If the result matrix is clipped between 0 and 1,

```
final_image = fftpack.ifft2(img_fft).real.clip(0, 1)
```

the final image looks like this:
[image]

Any idea what is happening here? I am expecting it to return the same image.

Comment: `np.abs` throws away information from the complex-valued FFT, so it isn't unexpected the inverse FFT is 'missing' stuff. If you are trying to do a round-trip forward/inverse transform to confirm it is an identity, then simply remove the `np.abs` call. If you really want the inverse FFT of the absolute value of the forward transform, then you shouldn't be expecting to get the original image back. And for the effect of the clipping, the image isn't as uniform because of the automatic scaling done by matplotlib's `imshow` (otherwise dominated by a few really large values hidden in the corners).

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense now.